# We finally have a weapon to win the war against the aliens. We don't know how to deploy it

Tags: science-based, weapons, science-fiction

**2234, April. Region 932 A.E.D.**

It's a hot day on Xenaas-891, and the fight isn't going well for our soldiers.

"Sarge, our exosuits are going to run out of oxegyn soon! There are 2 class 3 aliens coming in from the west, and a small squad of class 5's. What do you want us to do?"

Sarge curses under his breath, and takes a look around. "Stay calm, private! AT5522 - Take AT2342 and UT1121 and see if you can find a way to get behind the class 3's. Private and I here will hold down the class 5's."

"Yes sir!" The three troopers run to into the east, when suddenly, a class 7 alien jumps out from behind a rock and leaps at AT5522. *Hiss*

"AT5522 got his oxygen tank stabbed! Sarge, you better come look at this!"

"What in the mother of holy barbeques is happening to that bugger? Looks like he is.... what the heck? How am I supposed to describe that in my report!?"

**2234, May. Military Base 331 A.E.D.**

"Regiment MC331! Form up!"

The troops quickly fall in as a resource shuttle lands in the camp.

"Alright folks, our newest experimental weapon is here. BEHOLD! Cans of Perri-air!"

A wave of applause goes up as the bay doors of the shuttle open, and massive crates of Perri-air are rolled into the camp. Each soldier is distributed several cans to carry on his person at all times.

"Listen up! We've been getting massacred out there for the last year, since none of our weapons seem to work very effectively. However, thanks to AT5522 and his mishap, we've discovered a massive weakness in the alien biology! It turns out that these aliens use a cutaneous gas exchange system, and oxygen is both extremely corrosive and toxic to them. That brings us to the two ways we can use these cans! You can throw these pressurized hunks of metal at the enemy, and shoot the can! This will allow the oxygen to disperse and act as a grenade! You can also use it as a melee weapon, if you get jumped by a class 4 or lower alien! Just open the top of the can like you would a soda and let the air go free! You are not recommended to use this on class 3 or higher aliens! It does not contain enough air to stop you from getting squashed! **Am I understood?**"

"SIR! UNDERSTOOD, SIR!"

**2236, June. Research division on The WarDoctor A.E.D.**

It's been 2 years since the humans have finally gotten a fighting chance to survive on Xenaas-891. The scientists have finally developed our ultimate weapon.

"Tell me, Dr. Pepper. What exactly is this new weapon?"

"We call it the C.A.O.P.T. Once deployed, it produces enough oxygen to keep a 20 meter radius area class 3 and lower free for months. It takes about 5 minutes after deployment to flush out the area around it. You can use this to create barriers which the aliens cannot move through, or even as a zoning tool."

"It looks like a tree. What does C.A.O.P.T. stand for?"

"Ah, that's because it **is** a tree. A Copious Amounts of Oxygen Producing Tree, to be exact. A new breed, with thick bark for protection and quick growing roots for stability. There are some slight problems though - it doesn't handle impact from the roots very well. If we were to drop this tree in an upright position onto the ground from 3 meters up, it would shatter. Not only that, but the breed is extremely heavy. Too heavy for your largest shuttles to carry - they're close to 600 tons. We also can't manufacture these trees on the surface - we can only make them on some of our ships, namely The WarDoctor, The FrillyLizard, and The PepperoniStick. You'll have to find a way to get the trees from space to the surface."

"You mean to tell me that you don't have a method of delivery for this weapon? What the hell do we pay you for then?"

"I'm paid to develop the weapon, not the delivery system. Find someone else for that."

"You there!" *Finger points at you* "I have a job for you!. Design me a delivery system for this weapon!"

---

## What delivery system do I design in order to safely deploy the C.A.O.P.T. weapon to the surface of the planet?

A quick summary:

- The tree must not hit the ground at high impact in its upright state.
- The tree will self-plant itself once it's in contact with the ground.
- You cannot fly the trees to the surface via shuttle/plane, as it's too heavy.
- You will not be able to move the tree once it's on the ground.

Extra information:

- You can assume that the ground of Xenaas-891 is similar to the ground of Earth; mostly dirt.
- The atmosphere is similar to that of Earth, with the exception of it containing no Oxygen.
- Gravity is a stifling 1.2 times that of Earth.
- The tree is flammable.
- A.E.D. stands for "After Earth's Destruction" - technology level is futuristic, but please remain within the bounds of known + predicted science.
- Aliens have an air force.

If there is any extra information required, please ask in the comments and I will do my best to provide.

Comment: Why drop the trees at all?  Take the gas and drop it in cannisters on the enemy.

Comment: @Oldcat If we drop a gas canister, several things happen - 1) Gas disperses and you lose the long term zoning effect 2) Whatever canister you used to hold that gas in is now forfeit - in a fight on a foreign planet where you have limited resources, we don't want to waste precious metal

Comment: Gas still disperses when made by trees. And when you kill them, you take back and recycle the cannisters.

Comment: @Oldcat Yes, the gas disperses when made by trees, but with the trees it's continuous production versus the canister which only provides a temporary rise in the oxygen levels of the area. Who's to say that if you fire the canisters you're guaranteed a win? What if you fire the canisters and you lose that battle, and the enemy takes your canisters? Now you've given the enemy extra metal.

Comment: If it doesn't work, keep trying until it does.  Then you get it all back. Why do you think a tree would work any better - the enemy could approach from upwind and kill it.  Or use blowers to make wind.

Comment: @Oldcat The tree exudes oxygen in a 20 meter radius, meaning there is no "upwind". Ignoring the fact that this is in all likeliness a horrible way to fight an enemy, this is a fictional setting, and I would much appreciate it if you could put your efforts towards actually answering the question instead of trying to break it.

Comment: and as soon as exuded, it blows away with the wind.  Fictional doesn't have to equal 'nonsensical'

Comment: @Oldcat If it's constantly exuding out of all sides, it's impossible to have a 100% clean area for it to get attacked, since as soon as you blow what's already there away, new amounts of it come in. Also, good luck killing a 600 ton tree that has thick bark that was bio engineered to protect it from the scenario you just depicted.

Comment: <sigh>. Imagine your tree exudes smoke, not oxygen - like a smoke grenade. Now imagine a 40 mile an hour wind, and see how the smoke blows away from the tree toward the downwind side.  From the upwind side, there's no smoke.  And now your paradropped tree is **600 tons**?

Comment: @Oldcat Imagine a pillar with millions of holes on the sides that put out smoke. Even with the wind blowing directly against one side, given enough smoke production rate, you will never see the actual pillar. Then, yes, I'm saying to deal with a 600 ton pillar.

Comment: Only if the tree can produce more wind than your 50 mile an hour wind, and even then you will still see the tree through a thin skin of material a fraction of an inch thick.  And now this isn't a tree, its a magical device you are making up as you go along.

Comment: @Oldcat The pillar is just to be used as a substitute for imagining the scenario, similar to how you chose to use a smoke grenade. The tree has to be able to fill a 20 meter radius hemisphere with oxygen in 5 minutes, which is 55.851 meters cubed of oxygen per **second**. The question hasn't changed. Besides, 50 mile/hour winds are ludicrously fast. Where did you even get that number?

Comment: And your tree resists missile attack how?!?!

Comment: Here you go +1 my deposit, I'll return with a comment(answer) later after I skims through chapters in Sun Tzu art of war for business.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Why does it have to resist a missile attack?

Comment: @Aify The aliens have air power.  They could take them out with air to ground missiles.

Comment: @LorenPechtel They're aliens. Why do they have to have missiles? For all you know, their air force consists of flying swarms of melee attackers.

Comment: Use [*cheddarite*](https://plus.google.com/103474085688342665829/posts/c1j4FKH2eWm).  It soulds like [this kind of story](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Smashers_of_the_Galaxy_Rangers) is what you are writing.

Comment: Seriously, we can fight a war on a planet in *another solar system* but our best technology to generate oxygen is... a 600-ton bio-engineered armored tree.  Is there a market for retro-1950's scifi stories?

Comment: "Region 932 A.E.D.", then *later* "Base 331 A.E.D.". Your use of A.E.D. doesn't make sense to me. The acronym describes it as a time Epoch, but you seem to be use it as a region or other location modifier.

Comment: I agree with the majority of commenters. A tree cannot do this, unless it is being deployed by Harry Potter. Trees produce very little oxygen compared to this magical creation of yours. Given real biology, there is no way to make a tree produce this kind of oxygen.

Comment: Trees break down carbon dioxide to produce oxygen, but only when in sunlight. At night, the oxygen layer would dissipate.

Comment: If the oxygen production is fast enough in sunlight to prevent dissipation, how would the carbon dioxide get to the tree to allow the production of oxygen? More magic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Parachutes... uh, sir.**

You've ruled out shuttling them to the surface and apparently whatever brings tanks to the surface won't work. Really big parachutes work well though. Drop them from space with a blast shield or not at orbital velocities. A blast shield, or [heat shield](http://www.space.com/11995-nasa-mars-science-laboratory-rover-heat-shield.html), is a standard piece of planetary lander equipment. The shield protects the tree during entry and falls away once the tree is at terminal velocity (with the drogue). It won't get in the way of rooting.

[image]

If we can parachute vehicles to the surface we can do it for the trees. Adjusting the size will adjust the decent speed to whatever the tree can survive.

---

EDIT:

To save the parachute from the newly invented alien air force. Use large compressed oxygen tanks to provide oxygen for thrust to help slow and steer the tree as well as poison the air, killing any flying aliens who try to get at it.

---

Alternatively, if you want a more feasible solution than these weird trees which shatter with a slight impact but can support their own 600 tons without issue, you can simply drop water and perform electrolysis on it. You have a space faring civilization, it's likely that you can generate copious amounts of energy. If you're concerned about leaving canisters around then just build an electrolysis station and supply it with water drops from the shuttles. Each 60 ton load of water from a shuttle would produce 36,347,000 liters of O<sub>*2*</sub>. That would fill a cube 33 meters on a side with pure O<sub>*2*</sub>. Should be pretty effective. Just get the water from an asteroid if there isn't any on the planet.

Comment: Yes, this might work, but a big parachute is very slow, and liable to be taken out easily by the Alien air force. My fault for not mentioning that they had an air force. Will edit into question for future answers, but into the "extra" information section so that this answer remains valid.  Also, I'm not convinced that parachuting the tree will let it survive. Consider that the tree has to be launched from space - how will the tree survive the journey? It could easily burn up while it's dropping through the atmosphere, especially since parachutes don't typically deploy right at the start.

Comment: Are parachute drops pretty accurate? To address my own concern, I suppose you could have the tree on a massive mobile platform of some sort to move it where it needs to go. Then you need a way to get it off the platform.

Comment: @Aify You might explain then, why humans are fighting with soldiers on the ground without a way to shuttle heavy things to the surface against an enemy with an air force.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Very accurate. [We can get 27,215 kg to within 50 meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Precision_Airdrop_System).

Comment: The tree is meant to be so heavy that it's easily the weight of 10 tanks or more. While normal vehicles could be shuttled down, maybe in groups of 2 to 4, the C.A.O.P.T cannot. Even if the "largest shuttle" could carry one such tree, the troops on the ground would be unable to move it. @Samuel The reason why we can move it in space is because we're in a zero grav environment.

Comment: @Aify Put a blast shield on it. It likely won't be dropping from orbit, but from whatever ship *can* carry them.

Comment: Also, 50 meter accuracy isn't very good for a weapon that has a 20 meter radius. If you have horrible luck and actually are off by 50 meters, the entire weapon is now useless since you've completely missed the intended area.

Comment: @Aify 50 meter accuracy is *today*. You're talking about dropping genetically engineered plants from space onto an alien planet. We'll likely have improved parachute drops by then. Even if we haven't made a heavy ship that can land on a planet.

Comment: @Aify The alien air force could interrupt anything going to the surface, so whatever method you have of preventing them from interrupting shuttles *should* work equally well for the parachutes.

Comment: How do you deal with the "swaying" of parachutes? One bad angle and the entire tree tips over. At the end of the day, a parachute drop is still vulnerable to enemy anti-air defenses, especially one large enough to float a 600 ton tree. @DoubleDouble The alien air force consists of large flying aliens that the shuttles can out run. A parachute doesn't outrun things. It just floats down.

Comment: @Aify Clearly you attach to the tree above the center of mass. Perfect the alien air force is made of aliens, the tree is producing oxygen, the flying aliens can't get close to it. It's streaming oxygen as it falls, preventing them from messing with the tree directly or the parachute above it.

Comment: @Samuel the tree doesn't make oxygen until deployment is complete, and even then it takes 5 minutes to flush out the area it's supposed to. (That information is in the story, although now that I read it, it's poorly worded and I'll fix that)

Comment: @Aify I've edited the answer to account for the alien air force.

Comment: =) Question, how long does it take for the tree to reach the ground?

Comment: @Aify It will depend on when the main parachute is deployed. The drogue (the little parachute in the picture) is used to stabilize the tree during its descent. The main parachute can likely open up around 5k feet. The descent time would be around 10 minutes after that. Presumably before that it would be going too fast for the alien air force to catch it, but it could still expel oxygen during that time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the blast shield in your answer? I'm not sure how blast shields work, but I'm under the impression they either have to be a) under the payload as it drops (which leads to rooting problems after), or b) completely surrounding the payload in order to protect from intense heat (which also has problems for rooting).

Comment: @Aify hey guys, check this out. I think it gives you exactly what you're looking for.  "The 5-10K high altitude-low opening (HALO) improved container delivery system (ICDS) is a family of gravity-dropped 5,000- to 10,000-pound HALO systems using a wireless activation device timer system to trigger openings near impact and allow for rapid velocity through most of descent to improve accuracy."
http://www.kmimediagroup.com/military-logistics-forum/articles/400-military-logistics-forum/mlf-2012-volume-6-issue-4-may/5458-smarter-cargo-drops-sp-717

Comment: @zfrisch Not quite. It supports a lower payload than what I already linked in the comments and still only has a 50 meter accuracy.

Comment: @Samuel I suppose sir. I may have gotten a little overzealous. Still though, it is futuristic. It stands to reason that in this instance there may be a similar HALO system developed that is able to sustain a larger payload. In any case I have another idea that I'll post as another answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26594/discussion-on-answer-by-samuel-we-finally-have-a-weapon-to-win-the-war-against-t).

Comment: The aliens can't intercept it if you do [this](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/40735/11665). Just in case it helps.

Comment: It's a shame they can't be dropped at high velocity, because there's a real-world version of this: strategic seed bombs! Apparently [Thailand](http://anonhq.com/thailand-creating-forests-dropping-millions-trees-aircraft/) and some other places have been using this technique already... http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/aerial-reforestation-3.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Seeds.

They take a bit longer to deploy but they're easily portable, and a little engineering and [pink light](http://inhabitat.com/indoor-vertical-farm-pinkhouses-grow-plants-faster-with-less-energy/) should make them grow pretty quickly. They have the added bonus of being easily concealable and very tough until they're deployed. Then the window to kill them would be brief.

Drop them wrapped in a soil mat into the ocean (if applicable), let them grow, then send teams in to maneuver them into position.

You can also feed them to indigenous wildlife to infiltrate the enemy's camps.

You could even drop trillions of them on the homeworld from orbit - there'd be no way to find them all until it was too late. I used to work in a greenhouse. Ever dropped a packet of geranium seeds? [image]

Comment: This fails the "We also can't manufacture these trees on the surface - we can only make them on some of our ships, namely The WarDoctor, The FrillyLizard, and The PepperoniStick. You'll have to find a way to get the trees from space to the surface." sentence in the original post.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't sure that growth counted as manufacture, but I suppose it makes sense - otherwise someone would have suggested making the trees smaller.

Comment: If it were a normal tree and not a bio engineered tree, then your idea would have worked, if we assumed that the tree could grow in that environment.

Comment: +1 because I had the same idea, with a twist from the [Ice Limit by Preston and Child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_Limit).

Answer (score 5):

If you want precision and quick deceleration you could go the route of the Mar's rover "Sky Crane Maneuver", seeing as we're deploying to another planet it's not too far fetched that this technology would be relatively standard fare(though probably still expensive) in the future. Here's a link: http://www.space.com/16878-mars-rover-landing-sky-crane-guide.html

Here's the doctored up infographic:

[image: Tree]

Additional Facts:

1. It was developed for something moving at a velocity of 13,000 mph(21,000) kph to get down to 0 in the span of seven minutes.
2. There is a heat shield(obviously) that will take the friction of deceleration. It will glow white-hot because of the velocity and thus needs to be jettisoned on approach to land (in this case, not to set the trees on fire I suppose)
3. The chute created for the mars mission was the largest supersonic drogue chute ever created. A drogue parachute is simply a parachute designed to slow a fast moving object down.
4. Once the heat shield is jettisoned there is a radar that is used to find the ground and the sky crane( which is that sweet looking thing in the second picture) comes out of the aeroshell and is used to maneuver and lower the package away from the backshell and towards the mark.
5. After it touches down, the nylon ropes connecting from the sky crane to the package are automatically removed and the crane itself is moved away to prevent any collateral landing damage.

[image: Sky Crane]

Additional cool thing, if a tree was going to be developed to be dropped it might be a variant of the Baobab tree. It's bark is fire resistant, it's fruit is edible, and it is massive. http://www.smithsonianmag.com/travel/the-tallest-strongest-and-most-iconic-trees-in-the-world-759955/

Comment: Nice graphic. Don't you think the sky crane is the same thing as a shuttle dropping off the tree? Can it lift 600 tons? Also note that a drogue is used to stabilize and/or deploy a main chute, not as a primary chute to slow down a payload.

Comment: Nice answer! I'm just worried about the application of this to a 600 ton tree instead of a small rover. It's nice to see that the picture shows that the rover can be decelerated to 1.7 mph (which is significantly less than the 17.2mph from a 3 meter fall), but this is quite similar to having a helicopter or a shuttle slowly drop it off.

Comment: Well, technically you're correct. The difference to me was that it isn't just being shuttled down which meant it made the grade in my imagination, but I suppose it may be too far out of scope to be considered. I guess I am confused by how specific we're being with the technical aspects. With every answer you're going to have to expand the idea to make it fit. Nothing's going to realistically carry 600 tons to ground in a warzone with today's technology.

Comment: @zfrisch Actually... a bunch of these might work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-36_%28missile%29. I'm surprised that this wasn't one of the first things to come up.

Comment: @Aify  How do you mean?

Comment: Each one of those missiles is already a third of the 600 ton required weight. Go figure.

Comment: @Aify Are you seriously now going to allow shuttlecraft as long as they're rocket powered? You'd need 61 of those rockets to lift 600 tons.

Comment: @Samuel Wait, where'd you get that number from?? I was guesstimating maybe 5 or 6 rockets..... if it's like, 61, forget that.

Comment: @Aify Samuel's right. I'm assuming you divided the 600 tons by the weight of each rocket. That wouldn't work. You have to imagine too that with each rocket additional you would then have to add that weight to the total payload and compensate with even more additional rockets, so it would probably end up being over 60.

Comment: Yea, you guys are right, I completely forgot how to math when I guesstimated that number.

Comment: @Aify The throw-weight of the missile is 8,800 kg. That's how much the engine/fuel assembly can lift. It's the budget for your payload, guidance system, etc. 600 tons / 8,800 kg $ \approx $ 62

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for the calculation. Rockets is now clearly out of the question since say too much energy is required... unless, maybe antimatter powered thrusters to slow the descent of the tree? Almost like a giant drop pod...

Answer (score 2):

**Use balloons.**

The [*Pathfinder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Pathfinder#Entry.2C_descent_and_landing) mission used a combination of parachutes and balloons to land on the surface of Mars.

Here is a photo of a test inflation on Earth:

[image]

So, I propose to encircle the trees in a large envelope of balloons and release them from an aircraft - similar to [Samuel's idea](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21840/we-finally-have-a-weapon-to-win-the-war-against-the-aliens-we-dont-know-how-to/21842#21842). There are some issues with the balloons, but they can be solved:

- **Accuracy:** This is an issue with all airdrops. Winds can take over and blow things off course. I think that the balloon setup is massive enough that it would take strong gusts to move it too far away. Could it bounce? Yes. Solution: Use some sort of harpoon system to secure it to the ground at initial impact. Then deflate the balloons. This harpoon system could also prevent bounces.
- **Being shot down:** This is an issue with parachute operations; in World War II, pilots parachuting out of aircraft were sometimes shot down (at least during the Battle of Britain). The balloons should be able to reach higher speeds than parachutes, though, taking less time to hit the ground.
- **Descent speed:** The balloons could hit the ground at high speed. They will clearly cushion the bounce, and that could be enough. If you want, you could add on a parachute at the very end, or use thrusters on the bottom.

The trees must be deployed from space. The solution is to create an even smoother analogy to the *Pathfinder* mission, and add in a heat shield and other necessary components.

Comment: I like this one a lot - +1! However, if you have balloons at the bottom of the drop, how does the tree plant its roots?

Comment: I think the main benefit of the balloons on all sides was to let the thing bounce out the energy from the decent. There is no point of balloons on all sides if it's not going to bounce. In either case the g-force experienced would be significantly more than dropping the tree from three meters, so the roots would shatter.

Comment: @Samuel I would think that the balloons would add sufficient padding in many cases. It depends on how high the plane is flying.

Comment: @HDE226868 It's apparently from space. There are no planes that can carry the tree. The balloons will simply smooth out the impact. It's still going to hit with a whole lot of force. If the balloons are too big they cover the ground and prevent the tree from auto-rooting.

Comment: @Samuel Okay, then simply add a heat shield and related devices, to make a closer parallel to the *Pathfinder* setup.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did both of you skip the story part of the question?

Comment: @Aify I read it at least once. Did I miss something?

Comment: @HDE226868 Well, for one, the story included information regarding the starting drop location, which both answers initially disregarded or ignored.

Comment: Regarding the balloons at the bottom (which provide critical cushioning for landing), they could be made out of starches or similar readily-consumable organic materials. Alternatively, you could make them out of some sort of non-toxic polymer and have capsules of a non-toxic solvent inside the center of each balloon that aerosolizes on impact and dissolves the balloons from the inside out. It might not result in 100% decomposition of the balloons, but enough should be eliminated that the tree could successfully root.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the trees, pre-planted into pots affixed onto pallets with shockabsorbing buffers.  They will make oxygen fine without being planted into real dirt.  When the aliens are cleared out of a region, you can land and plant them properly.

Answer (score 1):

From Oldcat's [answer](//worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/21846/11665):

> Drop the trees, pre-planted into pots [...] They will make oxygen fine without being planted into real dirt. [...]

Comment thread on Samuel's [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/21842/11665):

> [...] the alien air force is made of aliens, the tree is producing oxygen, the flying aliens can't get close to it. It's streaming oxygen as it falls, preventing them from messing with the tree [...] – [Samuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3202/samuel)
>
> ---
>
> [...] the tree doesn't make oxygen until deployment is complete [...] - [Aify](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6453/aify)

Hmm...

This could avoid a **lot** of complications. Pre-plant the trees, and the aliens can't mess with them. Then remove the pot once it's on the ground.

Comment: This didn't fit in a comment. Although it is technically a half-answer, it does mean a lot of existing answers can carry on being right.

Answer (score 0):

Tree glider.  Giant gliders were used during WW2 by the Germans. 
[image]

I found these gliders to be able to carry a cargo of 23 tons and so for a 600 ton tree they would need to be scaled up 3000%.  Gliders containing trees would be dropped from orbit and so would need reentry shielding which can be jettisoned once through.  They would then pull up and expend kinetic energy via air friction during lateral movement through the atmosphere, gradually getting lower.  When glider and tree reach deposition site the glider would be very near the ground and moving just fast enough to stay airborne.

The glider then sharply pulls up to vertical, stalls and falls backwards a short distance.  The breakaway tail of the glider absorbs some of the impact leaving the roots of the tree to gently contact the ground.  Rear facing protrusions on the wings make sure the tree is oriented vertically.

Glider is then removed from around tree via the action of rain or large hoses; glider is composed of papier-mache which will break down when wet.  Glider material contains tree fertilizer to ensure tree health.